# Contact Geometry: Please Help Translate from French to English

Tags: translation-request, contact-topology

Everyone; I hope this is not off-topic for this site. I'm hoping to translate the following (the part after the ....):

> les orbites du flot de Reeb sont exactement ....les traces sur la sphère des droites complexes.

This comes from the section[Exemples - Structure canonique sur la sphere](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_de_contact).

I know flot de Reeb translates to Reeb vector field. I'm guessing the rest is about the span of complex lines on the sphere, but this does not seem quite right, quite correct mathematically.

Comment: Did you try to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry

Comment: Thanks, but I did not see any mention on Reeb Vector Fields of specific examples; there was just a very short definition of these Reeb fields.